# Unity/Blender - How can I hide walls from buildings modeled in blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I'm working on a Unity project with a city. The player controlls a flying camera and can move around freely. It's important, that the player is able to see the interior of the buildings. Therefore I need to hide the walls from my houses, when the camera is near them.
As the player can rotate the camera, only the 2 closest of the 4 walls should be hidden.
preferably, I would only hide the upper 2/3 of the wall.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Should I edit the blender models? (Can they get wall-checkboxes or so?)

Should I export every wall individually and put them back together in Unity? - As there will be over 100 houses, I could imagine this option getting quite laggy.

Should I hide them by manipulating the mesh-renderer in Unity?

Im not an expert for unity or blender, as you might guess. So I'm really thankful for any help!

Thank you a lot for your time and your effort! :)

Comment: Hi! I think at the unity questions you can find a solution for your question:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/343581/how-to-achieve-diablo-style-walls.html

Or you need another? Because of this question, there are amount of solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I also thought of something like that. However, I heard that you should avoid having a large number of GameObjects in your Scene. 
Dont you think, that might cause problem with ~100 Houses?

Comment: This will be a problem, but I think you need to use Occlusion Culling to avoid this problem as a first solution.

Comment: I didn't know, something like that existed! :D     I'll look at it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about you change the walls material to a transparent one if you are near them?